# error en algunos usuario cuando intentan ingresar con microsft en django

Tags: python, django, microsoft

uso django all_auth para la autenticacion de microsoft graph me conecto cn azure AD
pero a algunos de mis usuarios les aparece esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me comentan que solo sucede con algunos usuarios y que si los usuarios que tienen este problema cierran la sesion de microsoft e ingresan de nuevo pero desde mi login si les funciona esta es mi configuracion de django_allauth:

```
#DJANGO ALLAUTH
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'Seleccion_Contratacion_Personal.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'Seleccion_Contratacion_Personal.auth_backends.CustomAllauthBackend',
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'microsoft': {
        'client_id': os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"),
        'secret': os.getenv("AZURE_SECRET_KEY"),
        'tenant':os.getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID"),
    }
}
 
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'Usuarios.forms.LoginFormMicrosoft'}
 
USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True


ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True



# SITE_ID = 2
SITE_ID = 4
```

este es mi adapter.py

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        # No persistas el usuario todavía, por lo que pasamos commit=False
        user = super().save_user(request, user, form, commit=False)
        # Agrega tus campos personalizados aquí
        user.alias = form.cleaned_data.get('alias')
        user.account_uuid = form.cleaned_data.get('account_uuid')
        user.save()
    def get_user_search_fields(self):
        return ['usuario', 'email']
    
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        return True
```

y este mi auth_backedn.py

```
from allauth.account.auth_backends import AuthenticationBackend
class CustomAllauthBackend(AuthenticationBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **credentials):
        try:
            post_data = request.POST.copy()
       
            # Reemplazar 'username' por 'usuario' en el diccionario request.POST
            if 'username' in post_data:
                post_data['email'] = post_data['username']
                del post_data['username']
    
            # Reemplazar 'username' por 'usuario' en el diccionario credentials
            if 'username' in credentials:
                credentials['email'] = credentials['username']
                del credentials['username']
        
            # Crear una copia modificada del request con el nuevo POST data
            request._set_post(post_data)
        except:
            pass
       
        # y luego llama al método original
        return super().authenticate(request, **credentials)
```

este es mi boton de login

```
   <section>
                        <div class="button bsk-container">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-login-microsoft" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'microsoft_login' %}'">
                            <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cdn-testing.web.bas.ac.uk/scratch/bas-style-kit/ms-pictogram/ms-pictogram.svg" class="x-icon"></object> 
                            Iniciar sesión con Microsoft</button>
                        </div>
                        
                      </section>
```

lo que creo que sucede es que el boton me redirecciona a esta url "/accounts/microsoft/login/", si yo ingreso asa url inmediatamente me redirecciona a la pagina de microsoft

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si veo la url de las personas que tienen el error es como si no los redireccionara al tenant de microsoft[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]